# Flash a different region ROM

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms, rom, stock-rom, moto-x

I have a Moto X 1st gen. The model is XT1060 (60 means Verizon US version).

**I want to flash the XT1053 version of the phone (the US Retail version without bloatware) on it with RSD Lite.** Basically, the ROM is the same, only the carrier which is made for differs.

Am I doing right? How else can I transform my XT1060 ROM in XT1053?

*Thank you in advance and sorry for my lack of knowledge to explain this. I have looked for days all over the internet and asked forums and people. Nobody seems to want to answer or doesn't know.*

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. The XT1060 for Verizon is a CDMA phone with GSM world-compatible capabilities. The XT1053 is their unlocked GSM-only model. It would lack support for the Verizon-specific CDMA functionality that would allow it to work on your network. ROMs are very much, permanently, dependent on their device and can't generally be shifted to another device, except in the rare case that different model numbers are only for marketing purposes and the internal hardware is actually identical. It's not, in fact, JUST the carrier that's different. A lot of other functionality has to change to support that carrier.

Your only alternative would be to find a custom ROM built for the XT1060 that incorporates the specific functionality you're looking to get from the XT1053.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot have cross-platform ROM's from other device.But We can only install the custom roms which are dedicated for our devices. For this you can follow " http://forum.xda-developers.com/ " ; by selecting your device appropriately you can get multiple Custom roms.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys, I've solved it.

I got an XT1053 T-Mobile Retail image from internet. Flashed it with RSD Lite.

Now my XT1060 is XT1053 and everything works fine.